# MySQL changing authentication type from standard to caching_sha2_password

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I've setup a new MySQL instance on a computer and every time I add a user it sets the Authentication Type to `caching_sha2_password`.

This happens even if I set the Authentication Type to "`Standard`", it then changes it when I save the user. I've also changed the default authentication plug in to "`mysql_native_password`", but it still keeps doing it.

With it using the `caching_sha2_password` I can't connect to the database from .net core as I get an error stating:

> MySqlException: Authentication method 'caching_sha2_password' not supported by any of the available plugins

How do I get it to save users with the Standard authentication type?

Comment: If you use the newer authentication method, it also prevents Loopback (a node.js library) from accessing MySQL databases.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

I had the same problem today. The only way I found to fix it was:

1. executing the install file
2. select "Reconfigure" over the mysql server
3. In Authentication Method tab, select "Use Legacy Authentication Method"

It should fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks, @Meko for the tip. I just installed MySQL 8.0.11 and my Toad for MySQL 8.0 refused to connect with the error. Now after the reconfiguration, it works.

Comment: If you're on OSX the option should be in the Mysql Pane under system preferences. Press the button to stop the server, then press the "Initialize Database" button. Then choose: "Use Legacy Password Encryption". Then start the server again.

Comment: @Meko Perez, I am using node js with MySQL. Even I had the issues with authentication so I changed to legacy auth method and it worked. But, after that if I restarted my system and now again the auth is failing. I think once the restart of MySQL server is happening it is probably switching to the recommended approach to use latest auth. Anyone who got this issue resolved?

Answer (score 10):

Reset the user password with mysql_native_password

> `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' PASSWORD
>   EXPIRE NEVER; ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH
>   mysql_native_password BY '{NewPassword}';`

Answer (score 9):

Run

```
mysql> CREATE USER ‘username’@‘localhost’ IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY ‘password’;
```

Answer (score 8):

**For those of you that are using MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE and still struggling, the following worked for me:**

1. Under Navigator, click on Administration [Administration under Navigator preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvkdB.png), then select Options File.
2. *Administration - Options File* will open. Under the security tab, scroll down until you see "default authentication plugin". Mine was on caching_sha2_password. Changing it to mysql_native_password, clicking apply and restarting MySQL Workbench worked for me.

[Administration - Options File preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znhfZ.png)

I had to delete and re-add the user. It did not automatically change the user's authentication type back to caching_sha2_password, it kept it on standard.

Comment: This was useful for me, as workbench worked, but sequel pro didn't based on the plugin.
I prefer Sequel Pro for everyday use, as it has the basics in a cleaner layout.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/77818113/109787 for how to set this option by editing the config file.

Answer (score 4):

You can also do it with MySQL Workbench:

"Users and Privilegues" -> "Add Account" ->  Authentication Type: "Standard"

This user now can login with default login, i.e. for phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Thanks, I did the above steps, and it didn't work, because the account I used in my connectionstring was configured to 'caching_sha2_password' in workbench, only with your help I noticed it.

Answer (score 1):

```
import mysql.connector

def connect():
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
    database='mydb',
    user='root_new',
    password='root_new')
    if conn.is_connected():
       print('Connected to MySQL database')

if name == 'main':
   connect()

Output : Connected to MySQL database



1.Stop database server in preferences for MacOS.
2.initialise DB with legacy authentication.
3.Open mysqlWorkBench and Create a new user with standard authentication.
4.Create a new schema(DB) in sqlWorkbench.
5.Execute python Code in Eclipse.
```