# Can't connect to mysql server in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: mysql, wpf, ado.net, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to create ado.net model in visual studio 2019.
When I get to the point where I should create a connection with MySQL server I get an error shown on the screenshot.
I'm using MySQL for visual studio 2.0.5 and Connector/NET
Nuget packages: MySql.Data; Entity Framework 6
What can I do?

[image: the error]

Comment: like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52864853/how-to-get-mysql-8-to-run-with-laravel/52865317#52865317) changing the plugin of the user might be the easiest way to get past this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Authentication method 'caching\_sha2\_password' not supported by any of the available plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50088142/authentication-method-caching-sha2-password-not-supported-by-any-of-the-availa)

Comment: @danblack It does not. Tried both of them.

Comment: Did  you use mysql_native_password for your connection to try? If you are , could you add **auth_plugin='mysql_native_password'** in the conect to try, like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50557297/9862794) shown.