# RSA Encryption not supported - caching_sha2_password with django mysql and docker

Tags: mysql, django, docker

im trying to connect Mysql with django using docker, and i get this error

```
2061, 'RSA Encryption not supported - caching_sha2_password plugin was built with GnuTLS support'.
```

i tried changing user and creating a database with

```
// create a user //

CREATE USER 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'user';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
CREATE USER 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'user';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;

// create a database //

CREATE DATABASE user_db;
```

BUT still the sqme error message

in the settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'user_db',
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': 'user',
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

and in docker-compose:

```
db:
    image: mysql:latest
    environment:
        MYSQL_DATABASE: 'user_db'
        MYSQL_USER: 'user'
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: user
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    volumes:
        - ./data/mysql/db:/var/lib/mysql
    ports: 
        - 3306:3306
```

thank you for your help.

Comment: Please see following links to solve your issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50088142/authentication-method-caching-sha2-password-not-supported-by-any-of-the-availa https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49931541/mysql-changing-authentication-type-from-standard-to-caching-sha2-password?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: already tried that, i work with mysql from docker i don't have it on my system(i use Ubuntu), and the alter user and the create user solution are what i tried ,did't work, but thank you for your answer

Comment: have you tried to set everything to native password

Comment: i actually found out that this is a problem in MySQL version 8 , i changed it to an anterior version and everything works, with root or a user created, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 9):

I have solved this changing the conector to `mysql-connector-python==8.0.26` instead `mysqlclient==2.0.3`

Also, connection settings

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        #'ENGINE':   'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'ENGINE':   'mysql.connector.django',
        'NAME':     getenv('MYSQL_DATABASE'),
        'USER':     getenv('MYSQL_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': getenv('MYSQL_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST':     'db',
        'PORT':     getenv('MYSQL_PORT', 3306),
        'OPTIONS': {
            'auth_plugin': 'mysql_native_password'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Removing `mysqlclient` and adding `mysql-connector-python==8.0.26` worked for me even without the `'OPTIONS': {...}`

Comment: Beware, that changing your mysql driver randomly might incur heavy performance issues. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43102442/whats-the-difference-between-mysqldb-mysqlclient-and-mysql-connector-python)

Answer (score 3):

Seems a Debian version problem.
Setting the "FROM" python image to 3.10.8-slim-bullseye permitted me to mantain: caching_sha2_password, MySql-8, mysqlclient native driver.

```
FROM python:3.10.8-slim-bullseye
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added `RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y` in my docker file and it solved all issues.

You can simply run the command `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y` in the container before building.

Comment: If the above does not help, you need to install mysql-client-8

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        #'ENGINE':   'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'ENGINE':   'mysql.connector.django',
        'NAME':     getenv('MYSQL_DATABASE'),
        'USER':     getenv('MYSQL_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': getenv('MYSQL_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST':     'db',
        'PORT':     getenv('MYSQL_PORT', 3306),
        'OPTIONS': {
            'auth_plugin': 'mysql_native_password'
        }
    }
}
```

or in your DSN, add:

```
mysql://USER:PASS@HOST(:PORT)/DATABASE?auth_plugin=mysql_native_password
```