# MySQL authentication plugin set to mysql_native_password but server requests caching_sha2_password

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have an old PHP script that is using `mysql_connect("localhost:3306", "root", "password");` to connect to a MySQL server running locally. (Yes, I know this is a security concern; it's not staying that way.)

When I run the script (using PHP5) it says

```
mysql_connect(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password]
```

So, in order to fix this, I went into the database and ran

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' identified with mysql_native_password by 'password';
FLUSH privileges;
```

After restarting the MySQL server, I checked the `mysql.user` table to confirm that the authentication `plugin` was now set to `mysql_native_password`. It is.

I ran the PHP script again, and got the same error.

Then, not knowing what else to do, I opened up `etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf` and added the line

```
default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
```

I restarted the MySQL server. I ran the PHP script again, and got the same error.

At this point, I don't know what to do? The user (and the server) are both configured to use `mysql_native_password`; why is it requesting `caching_sha2_password`?

Comment: don't use the default authentification

Answer (score 1):

I changed the default method in `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`, underneath the [mysqld] section:

```
default_authentication_plugin = mysql_native_password
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).