# MySQL localhost cant connect windows 10

Tags: mysql, unity-game-engine, localhost, livecode

Here is the setups
Old windows 7 laptop I've got mysql installed on it. Project in Livecode connect to it. Projects in Unity connect to it.
New windows 10 laptop exact same versions of livecode, mysql and unity installed. None of them can connect to MySQL locally. I can connect with unity to the MySQL on my website just not the local one. Yes the server is running. Yes the 3306 port is open in the firewall. Yes MySQL Workbench connects fine to the database. I just cant get anything else to connect to it.

worked it out.
has to be an older version of mysql, .net connector needs to be installed, passwords must be set to standard authentication not sha256

Comment: have you looked intp the mysql error log, to see if there is a problem.if there ise nothing to see, enable general log and if that ios also not heloful, you could use wireshark to see what happens on the network

Comment: nothing in the logs. dont know how to activate general log will try this wireshark thing

Comment: you can see here what to do https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479107/how-to-enable-mysql-query-log

Comment: i can see some sort of log on try in the general log. wireshark is showing some sort of message sent between programs. its just not connecting

Comment: what does the log on exactly show, the logon doesn't seem to work, so try the logon in the console mysql.exe -u the name  -p password_here and see the exact error message, probay the user doesn't exist or hasn't git the rights.

Comment: 2022-10-21 18:14:27.926721 [theusernaame] @ localhost [127.0.0.1] 17 1 Connect ...

Comment: the firewall doesn't need to be open on the localhost, use for connecting localhost(so that it uses pipes instead of 127.0.0.1 which uses tcpip, and your app, doesn't provide yu with any clues or error message?

Comment: actually i went and redid the user and set the authentication type to standard and now livecode is working but unity still isnt working

TlsException: Handshake failed - error code: UNITYTLS_INTERNAL_ERROR, verify result: UNITYTLS_X509VERIFY_NOT_DONE

Comment: that is a ssll message have you ssl enabled on the mysql server, else disable it in unity

Comment: took a while but figured it out. wasnt any of those things. i needed to install the .net connector (didnt have it installed on the windows 7 computer) plus it only works with an older version of mysql. new version doesnt work

Comment: when you install mysql you have the option to use legacy connection also you can give the user the option top use legagy authetification see https://stackoverflow.com/a/57699078/5193536